# How to install Yaml and some other Python modules on OS X sierra?

Tags: python, macos, python-module

I am totally new to Python and programming and to use a software I got to have all the following python modules: yaml, os, re, datetime, sys, getopt, shutil, itertools.
but I do not have any clue that how can I download and install them for a Python 2.7.13 on OS X Sierra.

Thanks,

p.s: I know it's pretty a basic question, but please help me with a detailed answer, this is my first experience and got to learn how it works.

Comment: The dupe works for OSX too.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I actually read the question that you marked mine as its duplicate but that one is all about windows and I believe doesn't work the same on mac! does it?

Comment: I just said that it does. Install pip and use it to download packages.